# ftp-ssl fails after "Expecting TLS Negotiation"

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, ftp

The following code for simple secure-ftp fails on my Windows 7 computer but succeeds on a Server 2012 computer on a different network: If I remove the `EnableSsl = true` it works fine.

```
public static string TheContent(string url, string username, string password)
{
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = OnValidateCertificate;//returns true.

    string result = "";
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Timeout = 7000;
    request.EnableSsl = true;
    request.UsePassive = true;
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
    using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    return result;
}
```

I've tried *many* things. *Some* of them:

- Disabling the firewall. (Though I'm using passive mode)
- Setting port forwarding on my router.
- Using "active".
- Using FileZilla (fails the same way)
- Connecting to the modem by cable
- Much longer timeout

And more.

I always get an exception at `(FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()`

> "Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection
>   attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
>   after a period of time, or established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond."

When using Microsoft Network Monitor 3.4 I see that the error seems to be:

> FTP:Response to Port  , '234  AUTH command ok. Expecting
>   TLS Negotiation.'
>
> FTP:Response to Port  , '451  The parameter is incorrect.
>   '

Any ideas? Can it be that the non-server Windows aren't capable for this by default and something has to be enabled first?

Comment: Are you able to telnet to the problematic server using the machine where the code fails?

Comment: @jww I'm not sure what telnet is. But I _am_ able to ftp to it. Just not securely. (See the second line in the question.) Or is there such a thing as secure telnet?